# Python Json обработка данных

Tags: python, json

Всем привет.

Есть обьект такого типа.

```
api = {u'result': {
  u'count': 128,
  u'trades': {
    u'TIGVDC-PLSMI-6SOK7U': {
      u'fee': u'0.000002',
      u'vol': u'0.02000000',
      u'ordertype': u'market',
      u'ordertxid': u'OYOKDH-MB244-M7JSWU',
      u'misc': u'',
      u'postxid': u'TKH2SE-M7IF5-CFI7LT',
      u'cost': u'0.000672',
      u'time': 1547892327.0763,
      u'pair': u'XETHXXBT',
      u'margin': u'0.000000',
      u'type': u'sell',
      u'price': u'0.033620'
    },
    u'TNXVSF-7JKL7-KQBV7I': {
      u'fee': u'0.000012',
      u'vol': u'0.31993000',
      u'ordertype': u'market',
      u'ordertxid': u'OGNZKX-MN4GP-RFHOJJ',
      u'misc': u'',
      u'postxid': u'TKH2SE-M7IF5-CFI7LT',
      u'cost': u'0.004671',
      u'time': 1548087818.6903,
      u'pair': u'XZECXXBT',
      u'margin': u'0.000000',
      u'type': u'sell',
      u'price': u'0.014600'
    },
    u'TLG3HW-BZIHQ-FPTNGE': {
      u'fee': u'0.000000191',
      u'vol': u'10.00000000',
      u'ordertype': u'limit',
      u'ordertxid': u'OAFALL-XFMFN-P5ZKU4',
      u'misc': u'',
      u'postxid': u'TKH2SE-M7IF5-CFI7LT',
      u'cost': u'0.000119300',
      u'time': 1547986623.2719,
      u'pair': u'ADAXBT',
      u'margin': u'0.000000000',
      u'type': u'buy',
      u'price': u'0.000011930'
    }
  }
}, u'error': []}
```

---

```
dump = json.dumps(api)
```

Как вывести первый ордер, если его запись не известна?

`print dump['result']['count']['trades'][0]` не помогает.

Comment: Вы пишите что-то странное. `dump` — это **строка**, набор из буковок. Нельзя написать `dump['result']`, потому что эта операция бессмысленна для набора буковок

Comment: А как из этой строки вытащить первый ордер? Если заранее запись TIGVDC-PLSMI-6SOK7U неизвестена?

Comment: Чтобы вытащить из строки что-то, нужно её распарсить в Python-объекты. Но у вас и так уже находятся Python-объекты в переменной `api` — зачем вы вообще создавали строку `dump`?

Comment: По какому критерию определяется первый ордер? В JSON и в Python 2.7 словари не имеют предопределённого порядка — TIGVDC-PLSMI-6SOK7U настолько же первый, как и TNXVSF-7JKL7-KQBV7I и TLG3HW-BZIHQ-FPTNGE. При печати они выводятся **случайным** образом, и сейчас вам просто повезло, что TIGVDC-PLSMI-6SOK7U отобразился первым; при повторном запуске программы порядок может оказаться другим, потому что у словарей определённого порядка не существует.

Comment: В том то и дело, что мне нужно взять эти данные для дальнейшей обработки и записи. С json намудрил, согласен.

Comment: print api['result'] срабатывает, дальше  нет.

Comment: `print api['result']['trades']` вполне срабатывает. А дальше порядка у ордеров нет.

Comment: Спасио, сработало. Решил так. for line in api['result']['trades']:
 
 print api['result']['trades'][line]['fee']

Answer (score 0):

`json.dumps(api)` возвращает строку (`str`); чтобы преобразовать `dump` обратно в dict, используйте `json.loads(dump)`.

Словари в Питоне не упорядочены, следовательно и нет понятия 'первый'. Дальнейшие действия зависят от вашего желания: использовать `dict.keys()` или `dict.items()` и тд., и на получившихся результатах использовать нужную вам сортировку и `[0]` или просто `[0]` для выборки 'первого'.

P.S.
Если вам нужен именно первый, как выведено в вопросе, можно вытащить регуляркой (но это такое себе).
Или если в дальнейшем нужен порядок, использовать `collections.OrderedDict`.